# Shell Script - Echoing - Emails Results in a poor format.

Tags: shell, email, unix

Currently I have a script like this.

```
#!/bin/bash
Fun()
{
echo "blah1" >> File
echo "blah2" >> File
echo "blah3" >> File
echo "blah4" >> File
echo "blah5" >> File
}

Fun
Cat File | mail -s ' Here is a file bob@aol.com
```

When this file gets sent to my email I get my text like this.

```
blah1,blah2,blah3,blah4,blah5
```

Is there anyway where I can get my results like this?

```
blah1
blah2
blah3
blah4
blah5
```

I tried adding a echo >> file command after each line but it results in this which I do not want for various reasons later on.

```
blah1

blah2

blah3

blah4

blah5
```

Comment: Instead of running an unabridged script and posting a paraphrased/modified version here, could you sanitize your script and then copy-paste its exact code and output? Debugging and troubleshooting is all about details, and many details are lost when you can't copy-paste the exact code and output.

Comment: `echo` by default puts newlines at the end of each invocation. Given the script you posted (which won't run anyway due to a missing quote), the only place those could be being replaced is in `Cat`. Noting that `Cat` is not `cat`, you'll need to show us the definition for your `Cat` function - I suspect that's where newlines are being converted to commas, because `mail` won't do that, either...

Answer (score 1):

Use below instead of "echo"

```
echo -e "blah1 \n" >> File
```

OR use below to create a file in fun().

```
cat <<EOF >File
blah1
blah2
..
EOF
```

To append the same file.. use (note extra '>')

```
cat <<EOF >>File
blah5
blah6
EOF
```